# Failing to build moment.js typescript with MomentInput type conflicts

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I have the following typescript code

```
import * as moment from "moment"

const months = this.getMonths();
const firstMonth = moment.min(months).startOf("month");
const lastMonth = moment.max(months).startOf("month");

public getMonths(): Array<moment.Moment> {
    const assignmentMonths = _.map(this.internalBudget.categoryAssignments, a => a.month);
    const transactionMonths = _.map(this.internalBudget.transactions, a => a.date);

    return _.concat(assignmentMonths, transactionMonths);
}
```

That is throwing the following error for the moment.min and moment.max lines when running tsc.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Moment[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'.
  Type 'Moment[]' has no properties in common with type 'MomentInputObject'.
```

My tsconfig.json file is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node", "jasmine" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation that mentions a MomentInput object or figure out how to get this to compile properly. From the moment.js [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/min/) it seems as though I should just be able to pass in an array of Moments to min/max but I understand that this is just javascript and has no notion of typescript at that level.

I tried to construct a MomentInput object but the intention of that seems to be only for one moment rather than an array. How can I get this to build? The versions of everything are:

- Typescript: 2.4.1
- Node: 6.11.0
- Npm: 3.10.10

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by using spread operator like this:
Instead of `moment.min(dates)` I use `moment.min(...dates)`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Typescript 2.3.4 made everything work just fine. I didn't realize that 2.4.1 was just released a few hours before my question so there are probably still some teething problems with the moment.js typings right now.